# How to combine 2 function with 1 function in the javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating the function to save data using javascript pass to backend. Now I need to combine two function with 1 function in the javascript. Because I want to click one button can run the two functions.

`First function` - The first function is once I've clicked the button, the images will show in the page then pass to backend to do the save function.

```html
function save_qr(form) {
                html2canvas($("#createImg"), { 
                    onrendered: function(canvas) { 
                        var imgsrc = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
                        console.log(imgsrc); 
                        $("#newimg").attr('src', imgsrc); 
                        $("#img").show(); 
                        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); 
                        $.ajax({ 
                            type: "POST", 
                            url: "?f=" + loc,
                            data: { 
                                imgBase64: dataURL 
                            } 
                        }).done(function(o) { 
                            console.log('saved'); 
                        }); 
                    } 
                }); 
}
```

`Second function`- This function will pass to backend to do insert form data function.

```html
function save_qr(form) {
    var error_msg = new Array();
    $("#" + form + " .blank").each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            error_msg.push("The " + $(this).attr("title") + " should not be blank.");
        }
    });
    var loc = getQueryVariable('loc');
    var serialized = $('#' + form).serialize();
    var extra = '&action=save';
    var form_data = serialized + extra;
    if (error_msg.length < 1) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "?f=" + loc,
            data: form_data,
            beforeSend: function() {
                show_overLay();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    hide_overLay(data);
                    //$('#save').prop('disabled',true);
                    window.location = "?loc=" + loc;
                } else {
                    hide_overLay(data);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert(error_msg.join("\n"));
    }
}
```

That means I want to do the **first function** first to show the image first then to do the **second function**. The url using same location backend within in the two functions. Hope someone can guide me how to combine these two function with 1 function. Thanks.

Note：These two functions are worked if do it separate.

ERROR:

[image: out]

Comment: Simply add global variable like `var isImageShow = false`. Call wrap your code like `if (!GetPropertyValue) { GetPropertyValue = true; // 1st function code } else { // 2nd function code }`

Comment: Thanks @Karan answer my question. Can you write down in below, then if correct I can give you mark.

Answer (score 1):

Am I just blind or is it that simply. Rename the functions to `save_qr1` and `save_qr2` (Currently the functions have the same name) and use them in a new `full_save_qr` function:

```
function full_save_qr(form) {
  save_qr1(form);
  save_qr2(form);
}
```

The functions are processes synchronous. That means your save_qr1 will be processed before save_qr2. If you want a specific time to happen between the two functions you need to use something like `setTimeout`

```
function full_save_qr(form) {
  save_qr1(form);
  setTimeout(() => save_qr2(form), 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If like your answer can also save  imgBase64: dataURL  right?

Comment: You are 'just' calling your two functions within one function. So the whole mechanism should still work. If you have any issues - feel free to commend below and we try to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add global variable like `var isImageShow = false`. Call wrap your code like

```
var isImageShow = false;
function save_qr(form) {
    if (!isImageShow) { 
        isImageShow = true; 
        // 1st function code 
    } else { 
        // 2nd function code 
    }
}
```

---

If you want to check condition on `dataURL` then declare `dataURL` as global variable. And update condition as `if(!dataURL)`. Also update `var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();` to `dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();` so it will use `globally` declared `dataURL`.

```
var dataURL = "";
function save_qr(form) {
    if (!dataURL) {             
        html2canvas($("#createImg"), { 
            onrendered: function(canvas) { 
                var imgsrc = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
                console.log(imgsrc); 
                $("#newimg").attr('src', imgsrc); 
                $("#img").show(); 
                dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // removed var from here.
                $.ajax({ 
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "?f=" + loc,
                    data: { 
                        imgBase64: dataURL 
                    } 
                }).done(function(o) { 
                    console.log('saved'); 
                }); 
            } 
        });
    } else { 
        // 2nd function code 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edited answer which use `dataURL` for condition and preserve it's value.